# Retrieving only the most specific EReferences of an EClass

Tags: eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, eclipse-mdt

Suppose I have a UML model conforming to the *org.eclipse.uml2.uml* metamodel. Suppose that this model contains a `Class`, a `Property`, and an `ownedAttribute` relationship between them.

At the Ecore level, the `Class` and the `Property` are `EObjects`, while the `ownedAttribute` is an `EReference`.

My task is as follows: given an `EObject`, retrieve all of its `EReferences`. I can accomplish this using the following code snippet:

```
for (EReference eRef : myEObject.eClass().getEAllReferences()) {
    if (eObject.eIsSet(eRef)) {
        // found a relevant EReference
    }
}
```

Going back to the UML example above, this code snippet would identify all of the following `EReferences`: `ownedElement`, `ownedMember`, `member`, `feature`, `attribute`, `ownedAttribute`, `role`.

My problem: out of the identified `EReferences`, I would like to keep only `ownedAttribute`, since this relationship subsets all of the others according to the UML standard. However, the Ecore metamodel does not specify any kind of hierarchy between EReferences. What approach could I use to filter out the more general `EReferences` that I am not interested in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter out 'derived' references (org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EStructuralFeature.isDerived() == false).

Comment: Yes, that is the solution I also eventually came to. A slightly improved version in my case was to use org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EStructuralFeature.isContainment() == true, since this eliminates redundant EReferences that represent the same UML relationship in opposing directions.